# Echo sum for numbers in file

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I want to change hour + 2. I need to get 19:30 instead 17:30

Original code:

```
<tr><td class="time" width="100">17:30</td>
```

and I want this

```
<tr><td class="time" width="100">19:30</td>
```

I tried this:

```
$data15 = '<tr><td class="time" width="100">17:30</td>';
$data15 = preg_replace('|([0-9]+):|', "<?php echo ($1+2) ?>:", $data15);
echo $data15;
```

But didn't work, I get

```
<tr><td class="time" width="100"><?php echo (17+2) ?>:30</td>
```

I need sum of this two numbers.
Does anyone have idea how to do that?

Comment: What this has to do with `array` tag?

Comment: so, `23+2` would be 25 hundred hours? You will likely want to convert this to a DateTime then add hours. Sum the two numbers? Arithmetic? Do you really have to update a bunch of static content? Or.... blah.

Comment: You can do it so: `$data15 = preg_replace_callback('|[0-9]+(?=:)|', function ($x) { return $x[0]+2; }, $data15);` but you need answer to 
 @ficuscr question  before

Comment: Yes, it will be 25:30, but later I can replace 25: with 01:30. I know this is not smart but I don't have better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo can use preg_replace_callback function to change a matched number

```
$data15 = preg_replace_callback('|[0-9]+(?=:)|', 
          function ($x) { return sprintf('%02d', ($x[0]+2) % 24); },
          $data15);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7a0ba99cf04c74e4ddcf95264bfe7e46c16f042)

Comment: Doesn't work.PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function sum()

Comment: My mistake. Code works! Thanks. It works after 24:00 too :)